# Laravel посредники

Tags: php, laravel

Задача:

- Есть сообщение, которые могут оставлять пользователи.
- Нужно дать возможность пользователям редактировать/удалять свои сообщения.

Я реализовал это так:

```
if ( $message->user->id == Auth::id() )
```

Цель:

- Хочу перенести эту логику в посредник (из контроллера), но не знаю,
  как передать в посредник $message
- Из документации я узнал о    параметрах в посредниках:

  Route::get('messages/{id}/edit', 'MessageController@edit')->middleware('redactor:id');

Но у меня получается передать лишь строку, с статическим значением.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как указано в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware), посредник (Middleware) имеет метод `handle()`, который и выполняет всю работу. Примеры в документации тоже даны весьма показательные. Думаю, ее (документацию) стоит почитать...

Вот, например, как выглядит проверка в Middleware корректности возраста в запросе:

```php
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->age <= 200) {
            return redirect('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Т.е. Middleware получает экземпляр классического класса `\Illuminate\Http\Request`.

Ваш вызов

```php
Route::get('messages/{id}/edit','MessageController@edit')
       ->middleware('redactor:id');
```

для указанного маршрута передает во все Middleware дополнительный параметр `$redactor` с значением `'id'`. Для того, чтобы Middleware его принял, сигнатура у метода handle() должна быть

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $redactor)
```

Это, кстати, также описано в документации и сопровождено примером.

А вот значение переменной $id, приведенное в строке маршрута `'messages/{id}/edit'`, передается в метод `edit()` контроллера `MessageController`. И, как учит нас [документация по контроллерам Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers), в методе `edit()` должен для нее быть параметр соответствующий:

```php
public function edit($id)
```

Потенциально можно попробовать получить значение id для message в Midlleware, используя `Route::input('id')`. Но я лично [этот метод](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html#method_input) не проверял и не уверен, что правильно понимаю его назначение и работу.

Для Вашего случая проще всего не использовать Middleware, поскольку для него нужно как-то получить id. А его можно получить уже в контроллере. И ограничивать нужно не все операции, а только *edit* и *delete*. Это проще организовать именно в контроллере.

Лично я бы в модель Message добавил [локальный фильтр scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes) и в контроллере получал бы Message по id через этот scope:

Модель:

```php
    /**
     * Scope a query to only editable for current users.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeEditable($query)
    {
        return $query->where('user_id', Auth::id());
    }
```

Контроллер:

```php
    public function edit(Request $request, $id)
    {
        if (! ($message = App\Message::editable()->find($id)) ) {
            // для текущего пользователя запрещено редактирование
            // этого сообщения
        }

        // обработка редактирования
    }
```